# TabsListener not working as it should be

Tags: java, android, android-tabs

**I am new to Android so please explain in detail**

I want to build a basic Android app which uses Tabs. 
I have built a TabListener.

But it is showing me an error. How can i fix it?

Here is the code:

```
package com.adhish.tabs1;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MyTabsListener implements TabListener {

public Fragment fragment;

//Create fragment for Activity
public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment)
{
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction)
{
    Toast.makeText(ActionBarImpl.myContext, "You have clicked again !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction)
{
    transaction.replace(R.id.actionbar, fragment);
}

public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction)
{
    transaction.remove(fragment);
}
}
```

The error is in the declaration of this class:

```
Class MyTabsListener must be declared either Abstract or implement Abstract method
'onTabSelected(Tab, FragmentTransaction)' in 'TabListener'.
```

Please help me to workaround this issue.

Comment: try after adding `@Override` before `onTabSelected` method

Comment: try replacing `transaction.replace(R.id.actionbar, fragment);` with `transaction.add(R.id.actionbar, fragment, null);`

Comment: Post entire error log

Comment: @Apurva ... Moving this to a new question. Got this error fixed. was using the wrong imports. Will post the question link ASAP

Comment: This error should show before you implementing `onTabSelected` method. Current codes could not see this error

Comment: @Xcihnegn i have moved this question to another question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807563/tablistener-not-working-in-android-application